# Clarifications on ElasticSearch architecture

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

ES = Elastic Search

1. Can ES be used for persistent data storage ?
2. Is ES used only for search or for normal data storage as well,  like a normal JSON/Document datastore for an application dealing with Object data?
3. How does ES make aggregations faster ? Is it just Inverted Index and sharding or something else for aggregations ?
4. If we need to store time series data ….  TSDB or ES -  which one is better.. as in   if we need to store logs/metrics for a series of timestamps... which one is better .. TSDB or ES ?

Comment: I removed the AWS tag from this question, because there was nothing about AWS in the question. This question just contains general inquiries into Elasticsearch.

Comment: Yes you can use it for persistant storage, and es got a lot of features for logs (take a look at kibana, logstashs) and monitoring, this is one of its main use. Obviously time series are well suported. But as every database this could / or not could be the best choice, it s depends of that your are looking for...Agregation are really fast (faster than mongodb for exemple), but update are longer for exemple.